# If no valid price set is found for an event, CiviCRM fires a fatal error, shouldn't this be prevented?

Tags: civievent, price-sets

If I have a event with a price set field date set so that it is expires, when it expires but event signups are still active it cause a fatal PHP error and logs 'No Fee Level(s) or Price Set is configured for this event.'.

This should fail more gracefully, e.g. we should be preventing users from being able'register now' otherwise users can try to register for the event and be greeted by an error?

Steps to reproduce:

Create event and add price field to the price set and set it to expire via the 'expire on' field. Once expired, clicking register now will cause a fatal error.

CiviCRM version 5.11